# Remove JSON objects not containing a specific field

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I'd like to remove each object that doesn't contain the name field using node/js from the following:

```
[{
    "20": "Start Date:",
    "28": "15/06/2020",
},
{
    "name": "Jun/Jul 2020",
    "Monday 15th June": "Mon",

},
{
    "Monday 15th June": 15,
    "Tuesday 16th June": 16
},
{
    "name": "Charlie Sheen"
},
{
    "name": "Ray Liotta",
    "Thursday 18th June": "08:00-18:00:T5&6"
},
{
    "Thursday 18th June": "Theatres 5&6"
},
{
    "name": "Neil, Whatever"
},
{
    "3": "Theatres 1&2"
},
{
    "name": "Joe,  Bloggs",
    "Monday 15th June": "08:00-17:00:T1&2"
}]
```

The end output I'd like is:

```
[
{
    "name": "Jun/Jul 2020",
    "Monday 15th June": "Mon",

},
{
    "name": "Charlie Sheen"
},
{
    "name": "Ray Liotta",
    "Thursday 18th June": "08:00-18:00:T5&6"
},
{
    "name": "Neil, Whatever"
},
{
    "name": "Joe,  Bloggs",
    "Monday 15th June": "08:00-17:00:T1&2"
}]
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what this structure is but it's quite messy. What have you tried for the moment?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You'd probably want to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Thanks all, amazing - works a treat, appreciate it!

Comment: You should accept one of the answers.  It gives points to the person who wrote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Note that `filter` creates a new array containing the filtered elements, so if you want to change the original array, you will need to assign the result to the variable containing the array.

```
arr = arr.filter(obj=>'name' in obj);
```

```js
const arr = [{
    "20": "Start Date:",
    "28": "15/06/2020",
},
{
    "name": "Jun/Jul 2020",
    "Monday 15th June": "Mon",

},
{
    "Monday 15th June": 15,
    "Tuesday 16th June": 16
},
{
    "name": "Charlie Sheen"
},
{
    "name": "Ray Liotta",
    "Thursday 18th June": "08:00-18:00:T5&6"
},
{
    "Thursday 18th June": "Theatres 5&6"
},
{
    "name": "Neil, Whatever"
},
{
    "3": "Theatres 1&2"
},
{
    "name": "Joe,  Bloggs",
    "Monday 15th June": "08:00-17:00:T1&2"
}];
const res = arr.filter(obj=>"name" in obj);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = 
[{ "20": "Start Date:", "28": "15/06/2020", }, { "name": "Jun/Jul 2020", "Monday 15th June": "Mon",

},
{
    "Monday 15th June": 15,
    "Tuesday 16th June": 16
},
{
    "name": "Charlie Sheen"
},
{
    "name": "Ray Liotta",
    "Thursday 18th June": "08:00-18:00:T5&6"
},
{
    "Thursday 18th June": "Theatres 5&6"
},
{
    "name": "Neil, Whatever"
},
{
    "3": "Theatres 1&2"
},
{
    "name": "Joe,  Bloggs",
    "Monday 15th June": "08:00-17:00:T1&2"
}]
const filteredData = data.filter(item => item.name)
console.log(filteredData)
```

Comment: Why didn't I ask this hrs ago!?! Thank you, perfect!